Isolation transformer triggers the RCD in the lab
I am an electrical engineer, and I work in a lab environment. For some inverter measurements, we have bought an isolation transformer, but it triggers the RCD (GFCI for North America) in the lab when it is loaded. The isolation transformer is rated for 1500 VA and the oscilloscope that is connected is 300 W.
When it is loaded it definitely triggers RCD, but when it is not, the RCD triggering behavior is erratic. Also for 230 V AC input it has 245 V AC. It is a little bit out of specifications, but I am not sure if this is a problem. I have never experienced such a behavior. Do you know the reason why the RCD triggers? Is it normal?

Hi. Can you provide a diagram to show how the transformer and oscilloscope are connected? Also include the Earth connections.

What type of RCD?

Some poorly constructed isolation transformers can have leakage paths that you wouldn't expect.  Toroidal isolation transformers should be very good at isolation with little leakage, so maybe try a toroid vs. what you have now?
